# Put textfield and icon for date picker in same row

Tags: flutter, textfield

All I want to do is have a textfield and a date picker icon on the same line on my flutter app. When the user clicks on the date picker icon they will be able to select a date and that date will be set in the textfield. This should be pretty simple but I keep getting errors.

Also, the textfield and icon don't even show up on the screen now. Please help.

Here is the console output when I do a hot reload:

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86...
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/flutter_datetime_picker-1.5.1/lib/flutter_datetime_picker.dart:311:32: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'Color' which excludes null.
 - 'Color' is from 'dart:ui'.
                  color: theme.backgroundColor ?? Colors.white,
                               ^

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
An InputDecorator, which is typically created by a TextField, cannot have an unbounded width.
This happens when the parent widget does not provide a finite width constraint. For example, if the InputDecorator is contained by a Row, then its width must be constrained. An Expanded widget or a SizedBox can be used to constrain the width of the InputDecorator or the TextField that contains it.
'package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart':
Failed assertion: line 959 pos 7: 'layoutConstraints.maxWidth < double.infinity'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  TextField file:///C:/Users/nkane/AndroidStudioProjects/tonnah/lib/screens/transaction_detail_screen.dart:582:21
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      _RenderDecoration._layout (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:959:7)
#3      _RenderDecoration.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:1310:44)
#4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#5      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: _RenderDecoration#3d795 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=50.0)
...  size: MISSING
RenderObject: _RenderDecoration#3d795 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=50.0)
  size: MISSING
...  input: RenderRepaintBoundary#5840c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
...    child: RenderMouseRegion#4b1e1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      needs compositing
...      parentData: <none>
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      listeners: <none>
...      child: RenderRepaintBoundary#0aae3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
...        child: RenderCustomPaint#3a2b6 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: <none>
...          constraints: MISSING
...          size: MISSING
...  label: RenderTransform#c189e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    transform matrix: [0] 1.0,0.0,0.0,-0.0
[1] 0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0
[2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
[3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
...    origin: null
...    alignment: null
...    textDirection: ltr
...    transformHitTests: true
...    child: RenderAnimatedOpacity#16d0b NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: <none>
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      opacity: AnimationController#f80a1(⏮ 0.000; paused; for AnimatedOpacity)➩Cubic(0.40, 0.00, 0.20, 1.00)➩Tween<double>(1.0 → null)➩1.0
...      child: RenderParagraph#211e5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        textAlign: center
...        textDirection: ltr
...        softWrap: wrapping at box width
...        overflow: ellipsis
...        locale: en_US
...        maxLines: unlimited
...        text: TextSpan
...          debugLabel: ((englishLike subhead 2014).merge(blackMountainView subtitle1)).copyWith
...          inherit: false
...          color: Color(0x99000000)
...          family: Roboto
...          size: 16.0
...          weight: 400
...          baseline: alphabetic
...          decoration: TextDecoration.none
...          "Contract Date"
...  hint: RenderAnimatedOpacity#d7c0f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    opacity: AnimationController#02b53(⏮ 0.000; paused; for AnimatedOpacity)➩Cubic(0.40, 0.00, 0.20, 1.00)➩Tween<double>(0.0 → null)➩0.0
...    alwaysIncludeSemantics
...    child: RenderParagraph#9b614 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: <none>
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      textAlign: center
...      textDirection: ltr
...      softWrap: wrapping at box width
...      overflow: ellipsis
...      locale: en_US
...      maxLines: 1
...      text: TextSpan
...        debugLabel: ((englishLike subhead 2014).merge(blackMountainView subtitle1)).copyWith
...        inherit: false
...        color: Color(0x99000000)
...        family: Roboto
...        size: 16.0
...        weight: 400
...        baseline: alphabetic
...        decoration: TextDecoration.none
...        "Contract Date"
...  helperError: RenderConstrainedBox#a8da3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
...  container: RenderCustomPaint#7f6df NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderDecoration#3d795 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  TextField file:///C:/Users/nkane/AndroidStudioProjects/tonnah/lib/screens/transaction_detail_screen.dart:582:21
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1930:12)
#3      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:21)
#4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#5      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderPointerListener#48de7 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=50.0)
...  size: MISSING
...  behavior: translucent
...  listeners: down
RenderObject: RenderPointerListener#48de7 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=50.0)
  size: MISSING
  behavior: translucent
  listeners: down
...  child: _RenderDecoration#3d795 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: <none> (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=50.0)
...    size: MISSING
...    input: RenderRepaintBoundary#5840c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      needs compositing
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
...      child: RenderMouseRegion#4b1e1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        listeners: <none>
...        child: RenderRepaintBoundary#0aae3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: <none>
...          constraints: MISSING
...          size: MISSING
...          usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
...    label: RenderTransform#c189e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      transform matrix: [0] 1.0,0.0,0.0,-0.0
[1] 0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0
[2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
[3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
...      origin: null
...      alignment: null
...      textDirection: ltr
...      transformHitTests: true
...      child: RenderAnimatedOpacity#16d0b NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        opacity: AnimationController#f80a1(⏮ 0.000; paused; for AnimatedOpacity)➩Cubic(0.40, 0.00, 0.20, 1.00)➩Tween<double>(1.0 → null)➩1.0
...        child: RenderParagraph#211e5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...          parentData: <none>
...          constraints: MISSING
...          size: MISSING
...          textAlign: center
...          textDirection: ltr
...          softWrap: wrapping at box width
...          overflow: ellipsis
...          locale: en_US
...          maxLines: unlimited
...    hint: RenderAnimatedOpacity#d7c0f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      opacity: AnimationController#02b53(⏮ 0.000; paused; for AnimatedOpacity)➩Cubic(0.40, 0.00, 0.20, 1.00)➩Tween<double>(0.0 → null)➩0.0
...      alwaysIncludeSemantics
...      child: RenderParagraph#9b614 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        textAlign: center
...        textDirection: ltr
...        softWrap: wrapping at box width
...        overflow: ellipsis
...        locale: en_US
...        maxLines: 1
...        text: TextSpan
...          debugLabel: ((englishLike subhead 2014).merge(blackMountainView subtitle1)).copyWith
...          inherit: false
...          color: Color(0x99000000)
...          family: Roboto
...          size: 16.0
...          weight: 400
...          baseline: alphabetic
...          decoration: TextDecoration.none
...          "Contract Date"
...    helperError: RenderConstrainedBox#a8da3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
...    container: RenderCustomPaint#7f6df NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
====================================================================================================
```

Here is the code I am trying to use. Maybe there is a better way to do this but this is what I have found.

```
Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child:
                    SizedBox(
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 150,

                    child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                    TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: contractDateController,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        trxnProvider.changecontractDate(value); //, loggedInUid);
                      },
                      decoration:
                      InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Contract Date', labelText: 'Contract Date'),
                    ),
                    IconButton(onPressed: () {_selectDate(context);}, icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today)),
                  ],
                    ),
                    ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you are trying to put an IconButton beside a textField that takes all the "width" without providing any constraint to it. this is why these conflicts happen between the widgets, so as a result, no one of them gonna appear.

I recommend deleting the row and put IconButton in the SuffixIcon of the textField.

```
Container(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 50.0,
        width: 150,
        child: TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          controller: contractDateController,
          onChanged: (value) {trxnProvider.changecontractDate(value); 
          //,loggedInUid);},
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Contract Date',
            labelText: 'Contract Date',
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.calendar_today,
              ),
              onPressed: () {_selectDate(context);},
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: In my case I have to render a icon + TextField side by side, but only in the onPressed of the icon i have to open a datepicker and the TextField has to allow edit (withoud open the datepicker).